# How to add Main Menu and other widgets to gnome-do

Tags: menu, docky

I am using Ubuntu 9.04, and I installed gnome-do, and changed the theme to Docky. So far so good. Now, i want to get rid of the top panel too, and for that I need to add the menu bar to Docky. I tried creating a new menu bar and dragging it, but it doesn't seem to add widgets, only shortcuts. How do I add other widgets, like network-manager, Dropbox, etc?

Is there a solution? Thanks.

EDIT: A weird side effect is that Rhytmbox, Yammer, don't minimize in the notification area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the menu try Cardapio.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tvst-hotmail/cardapio
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python-keybinder cardapio
```

[This](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/06/use-cardapio-menu-applet-on-docky-tip/) article at OMG!Ubuntu explains how to hook it up to the anchor icon.
Or you could try GnoMenu a try, see [This](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/07/gnomenu-29-released-with-docky-support.html) article.

Comment: the add-repository doesnt work for 9.04.

Comment: see skalka's answer. consider upgrading to 10.04.

Comment: Cardapio is no longer being maintained and the last stable release was for Ubuntu 10.04 according to https://launchpad.net/cardapio

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Docky Icon (One with a Anchor on it) and add Docklets and Helpers from there

If you want to add any applications like Firefox or Terminal or anything just drag and drop it on the dock from the menu

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have with gnome-do (docky themed). Now Docky and Do are two separate apps. Go in the Ubuntu Software Center and install Docky. Then you have to choose with menu you want to use, I know about the existence of Cardapio (instructions [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/07/how-to-use-cardapio-menu-with-docky-and.html)) and Gnomenu (instructions [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/07/gnomenu-29-released-with-docky-support.html))

Comment: oh, thanks. I edited the title to reflect that. Also, I cant install Docky in 9.04 :( Theres no package in the default repos.

Comment: The official ppa of Docky has repos form Karmic, maybe you can try, but I'm not sure about dependencies.

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:docky-core/ppa

Comment: I checked Docky on launchpad, Docky only supports 9.10 and later.

Comment: So I guess it's better you think about an upgrade, plus Jaunty has ended his life three days ago, on October 23.

Comment: its my office pc, so i really can't :( Ill see if I can. 9.10 is LTS, right?

Comment: Nope, 10.04 is LTS, Karmic 9.10, as Jaunty 9.04, are normal releases with a 18 months long life.